# JMeter does not load user.properties when both files in same dir

Tags: jmeter

I have a problem with JMeter in that it does not load user.properties file when it is in the same directory, next to test script. I'm using Jmeter **5.4.3** and I can reproduce this issue with simple JMeter test:

[image]

Here are the files on my disc:

[image]

According to https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter
it should work:

> Note: You can define additional JMeter properties in the file defined by the JMeter property user.properties which has the default value user.properties. **The file will be automatically loaded if it is found in the current directory or if it is found in the JMeter bin directory.** Similarly, system.properties is used to update system properties.

But I got default value 1
[image]

instead of

```
someProperty=somevalue
```

Only when I explicity provide location of user.properties file with **-p** I got correct result:

[image]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. All tutorials seem to be following the same way as I do but it doesn't work at the ant of a day.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it should contain like like:

```
2022-03-04 10:32:55,284 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='C:\somefolder'
2022-03-04 10:32:55,287 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='c:\somefolder'
```

so if you but *user.properties* file under that `c:\somefolder` - it will be picked up.

So this [FileServer.baseDir](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/services/FileServer.html#getBaseDir--) **really** matters because it's JMeter's "working directory" and all files like .properties, CSV files, etc. are being picked up either from this directory or relative to this directory.

Assuming all above:

- Given you have your `someTest.jmx` and `user.properties` under `c:\somefolder`
- If you launch Jmeter as:

  ```
   cd c:\somefolder && c:\path\to\jmeter\bin jmeter.bat -t c:\somefolder\someTest.jmx
  ```

  the *user.properties* file will be loaded.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: When I execute ${__groovy(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)} it indeed  points to folder with my test and properties file so this seems to be OK, hovewer,it still does not work

Comment: it is completly alligned with logs that you mention,but still does not load properties file '2022-03-04 10:57:31,228 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base=...'

Comment: maybe it has something to do with the fast that I'm opening JMeter just with './jmeter.sh' and after that I load the file.

Comment: 2022-03-04 11:11:14,555 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='/Users/.../apache-jmeter-5.4.3/bin'
2022-03-04 11:11:14,557 INFO o.a.j.g.a.Load: Loading file: /Users/..../performance-tests/someTest.jmx
2022-03-04 11:11:14,557 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='/Users/....../performance-tests'

Comment: JMeter loads the properties from files **on startup**, if you want to pick the properties from `performance-tests` folder you need to launch JMeter from there. Should I translate it to Polish or to MacOSX equivalent?

Comment: if I run it with `./jmeter.sh -t /Users/.../performance-tests/someTest.jmx` I still got `Default base='/Users/.../apache-jmeter-5.4.3/bin'
2022-03-04 11:35:21,226 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='/Users/.../performance-tests'`. It only works with **-p path-to-props** ist's it a bug or something like that? :)

Comment: I repeat you 3rd (and last) time: you're launching JMeter from JMeter's "bin" folder hence it picks up *user.properties* from there.  You need to launch JMeter from `/Users/.../performance-tests/` folder

Comment: now it's clear,thanks